# Gradle doesn't download transitive dependencies from local jar

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a dependency locally but Gradle does not seem to take the transitive dependencies found in the pom located in **META-INF/maven/.../pom.xml**

Can Gradle take the transitive dependencies from there?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: The build.gradle is not important for this case, but the dependency is defined as follows: compileOnly 'com.mobbeel.http:mobbeel-http-client:3.10.0'

Comment: "does not seem to take the transitive dependencies..".Do you have some errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are hosting the jars in a local folder you will need to adhere to the [Maven repository directory conventions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) and store the pom alongside the jar. Neither gradle nor maven will read a pom.xml zipped inside the `META-INF` directory of a jar

Eg:

```
$projectDir/local-repo/com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.jar
$projectDir/local-repo/com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.pom
```

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = file('local-repo')
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.foo:bar:1.0'
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if your artifact has a parent, you'll need the parent there too (at least that was my case)

Comment: @haltabush For my application, I have springboot as a parent, do I need to add that too?

Comment: Probably not if your repositories also ahve an instance where Springboot is available.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a Kotlin-DSL way of doing the same, you could use this:

build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    maven {
        setUrl("local-repo")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(group="com.foo", name="bar", version="1.0")
}
```

while maintaining this same directory structure as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002072/8106170):

```
$projectDir/local-repo/com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.jar
$projectDir/local-repo/com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.pom
```

From: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_custom_repository